# Global footer in typeahead dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I have a typeahead menu with 2 categories, but under those categories I need to a button. How can I add this global footer, so it will be available when the 2'nd category is missing?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: have you tried looking at the typeahead examples http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/ specifically where they apply a custom `template` ?

Comment: Pricey, the example shows how to add a header for a data source, but the question was looking for a GLOBAL header, not a header on a single datasource.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to add a footer in each dataset but hide all but the last one with CSS, here's the code :

```
$('#search-query').typeahead([
        {
            remote: appUrl + 'franchiseesuggestions?query=%QUERY',
            name: 'franchisees',
            minLength: 3,
            valueKey: 'Name',
            template: [
                '<p><strong>{{Name}}</strong></p>'
            ].join(''),
            header: '<p class="tt-header">' + franchisees + '</p>',
            footer: '<p class="more"><a href="/recherche?q=%QUERY">All results</a></p>',
            engine: Hogan
        }, {
            remote: appUrl + 'citysuggestions?query=%QUERY',
            name: 'cities',
            minLength: 3,
            valueKey: 'Name',
            template: [
                '<p><strong>{{Name}}</strong></p>'
            ].join(''),
            header: '<p class="tt-header">' + cities + '</p>',
            footer: '<p class="more"><a href="/recherche?q=%QUERY">All results</a></p>',
            engine: Hogan
        }
    ])
```

And the CSS magic :

```
.tt-dropdown-menu .more{
    display:none;
}

.tt-dropdown-menu div:last-child .more {
    display:block;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What does the .join('') do in the template setting.

Comment: I think it joins all the "'<p><strong>{{Name}}</strong></p>'" together in a single result without space or anything. Note that this is an old version of the plugi, I think it changed since then.